# State Restoration and a Modal View Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog

How would you implement state restoration for a modal or "presented" view controller?

Let's say for example that I have ViewController and SecondViewController. ViewController has a single button.  When you click the button, it presents SecondViewController (using a modal segue).

Comment: So what's the question? You present the second controller, then what? You dismiss it, and you want to present the same instance again? Is that what you mean by "restore"?

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm actually referring to state restoration. (Edited the question a bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you recreating your modalVC before you presenting it.

EX: What you're doing

```
-(IBAction)presentModalVC:(id *)sender{
 ModalVC *modalVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"modal"];    
 [self presentViewController:modalVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

What you need to do:

create property of your modalVC and initialize it in `viewDidLoad` method